# Latex Beamer Class Remove Section from Headline

Tags: beamer

I want to remove a few sections from the headline in `beamer` class. How do I remove them? I want them in my TOC but don't want them in my headline as that becomes too big then.

I tried this but this removes the entire headline.

```
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use an empty optional argument for `\section`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section on ToC  and on Headline}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section[]{Test Section on ToC not on Headline}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Another Test Section on ToC  and  on Headline}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The resulting "Outline" frame showing both the ToC and the headline:

[image]